# ngrok failing to launch

Tags: docker, ngrok

Trying to run ngrok, I get the following warning:

```
WARN[04-19|17:54:51] failed to get home directory, using $HOME instead err="user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64" $HOME=/root
```

It occurs whether I try to start a tunnel or merely run `ngrok help`.
If I do try to start a tunnel (e.g.: `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite bilingueanglais.local:80`), I get an **empty screen**, instead of the usual tunnel information.

It used to work fine, I'm not sure what changed. If I remember right, I got the exact same error in the past, but things went back to normal on their own. I'd then assumed the service was down.

However, this time, ngrok is clearly up but the error remains.

#### Environment:

- Running ngrok on ubuntu:16.04 inside of Docker.
- ngrok is version 2.2.8 (the latest available version at the time of posting.)
- `$HOME` is `/root`

I installed Docker this way inside of my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
ADD https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip /ngrok.zip
RUN set -x \
&& unzip -o /ngrok.zip -d /bin \
&& rm -f /ngrok.zip
```

I'm able to run ngrok on the same computer on OS X instead of Docker, but would like to get things working again for Docker.

I'm confused by the error message and also, to some extent, [by the docs where it mentions `$HOME`](https://ngrok.com/docs#default-config-location). Is the issue with my path? What does ngrok expect?

Any help welcome.